# How can implement a function?

Tags: r, function

I have two data files as below:

head (RNA)

```
            Gene_ID  chr   start      end
1 ENSG00000000003.1   X 99883667 99884983
2 ENSG00000000003.2   X 99885756 99885863
3 ENSG00000000003.3   X 99887482 99887565
4 ENSG00000000003.4   X 99888402 99888536
5 ENSG00000000003.5   X 99888928 99889026
6 ENSG00000000003.6   X 99890175 99890249
```

head(snp)

```
  chr start   end SNP_No
1   1 58812 58812  SNP_1
2   1 67230 67230  SNP_2
3   1 79529 79529  SNP_3
4   1 79595 79595  SNP_4
5   1 85665 85665  SNP_5
6   1 86064 86064  SNP_6
```

I would like to find overlap between snp file and RNA file, so I used GenomicRanges R package and I have done below commands:

```
gr_RNA <- GRanges(seqnames=RNA$chr,IRanges(start=RNA$start,end=RNA$end,names=RNA$Gene_ID))
gr_SNP <- GRanges(seqnames=SNP$chr, IRanges(start=SNP$start,end=SNP$end,names=SNP$SNP_No))

overlaps <- findOverlaps(gr_RNA, gr_SNP)
subsetByOver <- subsetByOverlaps(gr_RNA, gr_SNP)
match_hit <- data.frame(names(gr_RNA)[queryHits(overlaps)],names(gr_SNP)[subjectHits(overlaps)],stringsAsFactors=F)
names(match_hit) <- c('Gene_ID','SNP')
head(match_hit)
            Gene_ID        SNP
1  ENSG00000000457.1 SNP_307301
2  ENSG00000000457.2 SNP_307307
3 ENSG00000000457.11 SNP_307365
4 ENSG00000000457.12 SNP_307387
5  ENSG00000000460.1 SNP_306845
6  ENSG00000000460.1 SNP_306846

dim(match_hit)
[1] 12287     2
```

Then I expanded distance for start and end position from RNA file ("start-100" and "end+100")and run scripts again as below:

```
gr_RNA1 <- GRanges(seqnames=RNA$chr, IRanges(start=(RNA$start)-100, end=(RNA$end)+100, names=RNA$Gene_ID))
overlaps <- findOverlaps(gr_RNA1, gr_SNP)
subsetByOver<-subsetByOverlaps(gr_RNA1, gr_SNP)
match_hit1 <- data.frame(names(gr_RNA1)[queryHits(overlaps)],names(gr_SNP)[subjectHits(overlaps)],stringsAsFactors=F)
dim(match_hit1)
[1] 17976     2
```

Now, I want to implement a function which takes the RNA table, the SNP table, and the expand distance, then give me final results.

Comment: it's really just a matter of putting the code between `function(RNA = RNA, gr_SNP = gr_SNP, expand = 100) {` and `}` and replace the 100s with `expand`. or you could copy the code into rstudio and use the `extract function` button under the magic wand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in R are defined like this:

```
myFunction <- function(parameters) {
    #function Code
    return(result)
}
```

[see also](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html)